# Increase height of the pop up background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onload

I want to increase height of the pop up background, while Selecting items from the drop down list .the  background of the popup should be equal to the height of the drop down list while selecting the items.

Also if I click the outside the popup background, it disappears. I want to show the pop up background un till any items selected from the drop down list.

**Html**

```
<div class="maintext">
    <h2> Main text goes here...</h2>
</div>
<div id="boxes">
    <div id="dialog" class="window">
        <div id="san">
            <section>
                <select class="cs-select cs-skin-elastic">
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Select a Country</option>
                    <option value="france" data-class="flag-france">France</option>
                    <option value="brazil" data-class="flag-brazil">Brazil</option>
                    <option value="argentina" data-class="flag-argentina">Argentina</option>
                    <option value="south-africa" data-class="flag-safrica">South Africa</option>
                </select>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 2478px; font-size: 32pt; color: white; height: 1202px; display: none; opacity: 0.4;" id="mask"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#mask {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  z-index:9000;
  background-color:#26262c;
  display:none;
}  
#boxes .window {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width:440px;
  height:850px;
  display:none;
  z-index:9999;
  padding:20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
#boxes #dialog {
  width:450px; 
  height:auto;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  background-color:#ffffff;
  font-size: 15pt;
}

.agree:hover{
  background-color: #D1D1D1;
}
.popupoption:hover{
    background-color:#D1D1D1;
    color: green;
}
.popupoption2:hover{
    color: red;
}
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

        var id = '#dialog';

        //Get the screen height and width
        var maskHeight = $(document).height();
        var maskWidth = $(window).width();

        //Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
        $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

        //transition effect     
        $('#mask').fadeIn(500); 
        $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.9);  

        //Get the window height and width
        var winH = $(window).height();
        var winW = $(window).width();

        //Set the popup window to center
        $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
        $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);

        //transition effect
        $(id).fadeIn(2000);     

    //if close button is clicked
    $('.window .close').click(function (e) {
        //Cancel the link behavior
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#mask').hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });     

    //if mask is clicked
    $('#mask').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });     

});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/j3su0d4p/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this `javascript` to your code, it will solve your height issue. It will also restrict to close popup if select box is not selected yet. Once you select any value from `select options` you will be able to make your popup disappear.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

    var id = '#dialog';

    //Get the screen height and width
    var maskHeight = $(document).height();
    var maskWidth = $(window).width();

    //Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
    $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

    //transition effect     
    $('#mask').fadeIn(500); 
    $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.9);  

    //Get the window height and width
    var winH = $(window).height();
    var winW = $(window).width();

    //Set the popup window to center
    $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
    $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);

    //transition effect
    $(id).fadeIn(2000);     

//if close button is clicked
$('.window .close').click(function (e) {
    //Cancel the link behavior
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#mask').hide();
    $('.window').hide();
});     

//if mask is clicked
$('#mask').click(function () {
   var val =  $( ".cs-select option:selected" ).text();
   if(val == 'Select a Country'){
    return;
    }
    $(this).hide();
    $('.window').hide();
});         

   $(document).click(function () {
       if (!$(".cs-select ").is(":focus")) {
        $('#dialog').css({'height':23});
       }else{
        var height = 17;
        $('.cs-select option').each(function (item) {
        height = height +17;
        })
       if($('#dialog').height() < 25){
       $('#dialog').css({'height':height});
      }else{
     $('#dialog').css({'height':23});
      }
     }
  });   

});
```

Try this code. It will set your popup height according to the options listed in select input. No matter how many option are there it will calculate the height dynamically.

Comment: Once i choose drop down list value it's working fine..again i choose same value it's not working

Comment: @IvinRaj Yes you are right, Updated my answer. Please check now. thnks

Comment: @IvinRaj there is still an issue when you click outside the select box when options are open, resolving that. :)

Comment: @IvinRaj Edited my answer. You can check now. Please let me know if you find any issue. thnks :)

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this snippet, assuming `<select>` height is 20px.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 

  var id = '#dialog';
 
  //Get the screen height and width
  var maskHeight = $(document).height();
  var maskWidth = $(window).width();
  
  var selectElement = $('.cs-select');
  
  selectElement.parent('section').css('height', (20 * selectElement.children().length) + 'px');
 
  //Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
  $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});
  
  //transition effect  
  $('#mask').fadeIn(500); 
  $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.9); 
 
  //Get the window height and width
  var winH = $(window).height();
  var winW = $(window).width();
              
  //Set the popup window to center
  $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
  $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);
 
  //transition effect
  $(id).fadeIn(2000);  
 
 //if close button is clicked
 $('.window .close').click(function (e) {
  //Cancel the link behavior
  e.preventDefault();
  
  $('#mask').hide();
  $('.window').hide();
 });  
 
 //if mask is clicked
 /*
 $('#mask').click(function () {
  $(this).hide();
  $('.window').hide();
 });  
 */
 $(selectElement).on('change', function(){
  $('#mask, .window').hide();
 });
});
```

```css
#mask {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  z-index:9000;
  background-color:#26262c;
  display:none;
}  
#boxes .window {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width:440px;
  height:850px;
  display:none;
  z-index:9999;
  padding:20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
#boxes #dialog {
  width:450px; 
  height:auto;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  background-color:#ffffff;
  font-size: 15pt;
}

.agree:hover{
  background-color: #D1D1D1;
}
.popupoption:hover{
 background-color:#D1D1D1;
 color: green;
}
.popupoption2:hover{
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


                <div class="maintext">
<h2> Main text goes here...</h2>
</div>
<div id="boxes">
                    <div id="dialog" class="window">
                        <div id="san">
                            <section>
                                <select class="cs-select cs-skin-elastic">
                                    <option value="" disabled selected>Select a Country</option>
                                    <option value="france" data-class="flag-france">France</option>
                                    <option value="brazil" data-class="flag-brazil">Brazil</option>
                                    <option value="argentina" data-class="flag-argentina">Argentina</option>
                                    <option value="south-africa" data-class="flag-safrica">South Africa</option>
                                    <option value="france" data-class="flag-france">France</option>
                                    <option value="brazil" data-class="flag-brazil">Brazil</option>
                                    <option value="argentina" data-class="flag-argentina">Argentina</option>
                                    <option value="south-africa" data-class="flag-safrica">South Africa</option>
                                </select>
                            </section>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="width: 2478px; font-size: 32pt; color: white; height: 1202px; display: none; opacity: 0.4;" id="mask"></div>
                </div>
```

Comment: I can see here height is fixed 20 px . I want to increase the height dynamically as the height of the drop down list @Vilas Kumkar

Comment: @IvinRaj Do you want to set pop up height when you clicks on <select> and options appears? OR I've updated my post with few more additions of option in <select> and jQuery code does the rest things to manage height of pop up.

Answer (score 1):

check below snippet, you can revert the `height` of `dialog` when user select the Country.

I have removed below code as per your requirment

```
$('#mask').click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $('.window').hide();
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 

  var id = '#dialog';
 
  //Get the screen height and width
  var maskHeight = $(document).height();
  var maskWidth = $(window).width();
 
  //Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
  $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});
  
  //transition effect  
  $('#mask').fadeIn(500); 
  $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.9); 
 
  //Get the window height and width
  var winH = $(window).height();
  var winW = $(window).width();
              
  //Set the popup window to center
  $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
  $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);
 
  //transition effect
  $(id).fadeIn(2000);  
 
 //if close button is clicked
 $('.window .close').click(function (e) {
  //Cancel the link behavior
  e.preventDefault();
  
  $('#mask').hide();
  $('.window').hide();
 });  
 
 //if mask is clicked
 /*$('#mask').click(function () {
  $(this).hide();
  $('.window').hide();
 });*/  
  
  $("select.cs-select").on('click', function(){
   $("#dialog").height($('select.cs-select option').length*22)
  })
  
 
});
```

```css
#mask {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  z-index:9000;
  background-color:#26262c;
  display:none;
}  
#boxes .window {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width:440px;
  height:850px;
  display:none;
  z-index:9999;
  padding:20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
#boxes #dialog {
  width:450px; 
  height:auto;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  background-color:#ffffff;
  font-size: 15pt;
}

.agree:hover{
  background-color: #D1D1D1;
}
.popupoption:hover{
 background-color:#D1D1D1;
 color: green;
}
.popupoption2:hover{
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="maintext">
<h2> Main text goes here...</h2>
</div>
<div id="boxes">
                    <div id="dialog" class="window">
                        <div id="san">
                            <section>
                                <select class="cs-select cs-skin-elastic">
                                    <option value="" disabled selected>Select a Country</option>
                                    <option value="france" data-class="flag-france">France</option>
                                    <option value="brazil" data-class="flag-brazil">Brazil</option>
                                    <option value="argentina" data-class="flag-argentina">Argentina</option>
                                    <option value="south-africa" data-class="flag-safrica">South Africa</option>
                                </select>
                            </section>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="width: 2478px; font-size: 32pt; color: white; height: 1202px; display: none; opacity: 0.4;" id="mask"></div>
                </div>
```

Comment: It's now working @aje   if i click the outside the popup background ,it disappear. I want to show the pop up background un till any items selected from the drop down list.

Comment: Any way Thanks @aje